# Pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In **pySpark** I would change the number of partitions when I load the data.

```
df_sp = spark.read\
             .format('csv')\
             .option("header", "true")\
             .option("mode", "FAILFAST")\
             .option("inferSchema", "true")\
             .option("sep", ",")\
             .load(os.path.join(dirPath, nameFile))
```

Using **pySpark**, it possible to tune the number of partition at loading time?

Comment: Just add ".repartition(x)" at the end of your command.

Comment: Why?..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `repartition(number of partitions)` at the end of your code. But please make sure to follow the guidelines as it involves full shuffle operation. Alternatively, if you would like to decrease the number of partitions you could use `coalesce`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`. It's `134217728` (128 MB) by default.